# Import error on rhel7 machine when running rhel6 built executable

Tags: gcc, build, centos, g++, rhel

I have my c++ project on rhel6 and it works fine.
But on a rhel7 machine, it throws the following error :

> ImportError: liblzma.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory

Now, I see, that on rhel7 machine we have :

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep "liblzma" 
    liblzma.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/liblzma.so.5
    liblzma.so.5 (libc6) => /lib/liblzma.so.5
    liblzma.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/liblzma.so
```

and on rhel6 machine we have :

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep liblzma
    liblzma.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.0
    liblzma.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so
```

How can I correct this error?
Since rhel6 build executables should/can work on rhel7. (any later version of rhel6)

Answer (score 2):

The older version of the library required (`/usr/lib64/liblzma.so.0`) is provided by package `xz-compat-libs`. So simply:

```
yum install xz-compat-libs
```

Comment: No need to install...since the liblzma on rhel7 already supports the rhel6 liblzma.

Answer (score -2):

Simply creating a link on RHEL7 machine will do the job.

```
$ ln -s  /lib64/liblzma.so  liblzma.so.0
```

Then you can add the directory in which the link was created to the enviornment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH". This env variable is used to find dynamic libraries your code wants to use.

Comment: Your app binary was compiled against an older lib. Even the newer lib *may* (and may not) have full ABI compatibility, dealing with the issue by manually creating symbolic link and overriding env var is far less preferable than simply installing minimalistic compat package. Especially so on an enterprise system.